# Can't change page p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have implemented code to do a table lazy in primefaces so I have method paginated which ones retrieves info. The problem  the number of each page it is not showed. So if I have 100 I only see 15 elements anymore. The page button is not showed.

Like in this screenshot:

[image]

In the bean:

```
 @PostConstruct
 public void init() {
    listadoPedidos = new LazyDataModel<Pedido>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public List<Pedido> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, sortOrder sortOrder,
                Map<String, Object> filters) {
            List<Pedido> lista = new ArrayList<Pedido>();
            boolean ordenar = sortOrder == SortOrder.ASCENDING ? true : false;

            try {
                lista = commonService.obtenerListaPaginada(Pedido.class, first, pageSize, "", "", "", "", campos);
                listadoPedidos.setRowCount(lista.size());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                MensajesErrores.error(e.getMessage());
            }
            return lista;
        }
    };
 }
```

And the JSF is:

```
                   <p:dataTable 
                    id="tablaUsuario" 
                    rowIndexVar="secuencial"
                    emptyMessage="#{msgs.lbl_no_hay_datos}"
                    value="#{pedidoBean.listadoPedidos}" 
                    var="_pedido"
                    paginator="true" 
                    paginatorPosition="top" 
                    style="width:100%"
                    selection="#{pedidoBean.pedido}" 
                    selectionMode="single"
                    rowKey="#{_pedido.rowKey}" 
                    sortBy="#{_pedido.id}"
                    sortOrder="DESCENDING" 
                    lazy="true" 
                    rows="15" 
                    paginatorTemplate="
                    {CurrentPageReport}  
                    {FirstPageLink}
                    {PreviousPageLink} 
                    {PageLinks} 
                    {NextPageLink} 
                    {LastPageLink} 
                    {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="15,25,50,100"
                 >

                    <p:column filterStyleClass="input-text"
                        styleClass="columnaDTCodigo tableCell"
                        headerText="#{msgs.lbl_numero}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{_pedido.id}" />
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
```

I really don´t see the error, the dropdown With number of register works well.

Comment: Uhh... there is a page button in your image

Comment: Kukeltje the case is that  should be three buttons

Comment: There are 4 buttons and there should be 4. All normal

Comment: No. Buttons 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was in this line:
listadoPedidos.setRowCount(lista.size());
replace with
listadoPedidos.setRowCount(TOTAL_ROWS_IN_DATABASE);